# Page_Load is not processing after async method obtains the required value

Tags: asynchronous, pageload

I have a page load that I am having difficulty with getting it to obtain a value from an async button click. The code is below. I am very new to this so please take that into consideration. What happens is essentially the code seems to just stop after the button is clicked and the GetAuthorizationCode executes. I get the value back on the temp Response in getReportButton_Click, but no other methods are executed on the Page_Load section. Essentially, I had this working in an older version of the Microsoft.Identity reference, but after upgrading it required switching many components to async and that is where I am stuck now.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Params.Get("code") != null)
        {
            Session["AccessToken"] = GetAccessToken();
            Response.Redirect("/Default.aspx");
        }

        if (Session["AccessToken"] != null)
        {
            accessToken.Value = Session["AccessToken"].ToString();
            GetReport(0);
        }
    }


 protected async void getReportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var temp = await GetAuthorizationCode();
        Response.Write(temp);
    }

public async Task<string> GetAuthorizationCode()
    {
        var serviceUri = "XXXXXXXX";
        var clientID = "XXXXXXXXX";
        var userName = $"XXXXXXXX";
        var password = "XXXXXXXXX";

        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var requestParameters = new NameValueCollection();

            requestParameters.Add("resource", serviceUri);
            requestParameters.Add("client_id", clientID);
            requestParameters.Add("grant_type", "password");
            requestParameters.Add("username", userName);
            requestParameters.Add("password", password);
            requestParameters.Add("scope", "openid");

            var url = $"XXXXXXXXXXXX";
            var responsebytes = await webClient.UploadValuesTaskAsync(url, "POST", requestParameters);
            var responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
            return responsebody;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just realized that in the previous code I was returning the data in a params property and checking for the existence of a code parameter. In the new version of the code I am not doing this which I believe is why it stops after the async button click task.

Comment: I have cleaned up most of the code, but the issue I am struggling with is having the page_load wait for the getReportButton_Click return value.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing multiple aspects of this code to the point the original post isn't close to the ending code. Log story short, I pulled the GetAuthorizationCode() under the button click and moved it to the page_load, storing the output to a global variable. I then pass that global variable to the button click action to call the other async tasks.